# Intentional Overlapping Cards in Bootstrap - text is pushed off to the side

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a design I am coding using Bootstrap which has overlapping cards.  I have the layout working (with a little help from jQuery) but the text on the top cards is pushed off to the side of the bottom card.

I'm stumped as to how I might get the top card content . (i.e. the XXXs) properly aligned in their respective top cards.

Here is a screenshot of how it looks today.

[image]

I'd like it to look like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class=" js flexbox canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Overlap</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
body {
  background-color: #81DFE8;
}

.background-card {
  background: #EFEFEF;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6));
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #404040;
  z-index:-1;        
}
.card {
  background: #EFEFEF;
  margin: 15px 30px;
  padding: 30px 75px 45px 50px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #404040;
}

#card-entity-header {
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.card-title {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.card-subtitle1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}
.card-subtitle1 small {
  font-size: 80%;
  font-style: italic;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>


</head>
<body>


<div>
    <div class="container"> 

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="col-sm-7 background-card">
                    <div id="card-entity-header" "="">
                        <div class="card-title">Title</div>
                        <div class="card-subtitle1">Sub-Title</div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="page-cards-background">
                        <div>&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <br><br>
                <div id="page-cards">
                    <div class="card">
                        xxx<br>xxx<br>xxx<br>xxx<br>xxx<br>xxx<br>xxx<br> 
                    </div>      
                    <div class="card">
                        xxx<br>xxx<br>xxx<br>xxx<br>xxx<br>xxx<br>xxx<br> 
                        888<br>xxx<br>xxx<br>xxx<br>xxx<br>xxx<br>xxx<br> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>


<script>

$("#page-cards").css("padding-top", 60 + parseInt($("#card-entity-header").height()));
$("#page-cards-background").height( parseInt($("#page-cards").height()) + 45);

</script>


</body></html>
```

Comment: I would advise against hard coding your styles inline. (Width/Height/Z-index properties). Would you be able to provide more detail on what you want the result to look like?

Comment: Yeah - caught the inline after I posted.  Agree - I have removed the inline styles and added a mockup of the desired look

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with some changes in HTML. Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/hLs7sppd/

```css
body {
  background-color: #81DFE8;
}

.background-card {
  background: #EFEFEF;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6));
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #404040;
  z-index: -1;
}

.card {
  background: #EFEFEF;
  margin: 15px 30px;
  padding: 30px 75px 45px 50px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #404040;
}

#card-entity-header {
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.card-title {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.card-subtitle1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.card-subtitle1 small {
  font-size: 80%;
  font-style: italic;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-7 background-card">
          <div id="card-entity-header">
            <div class="card-title">Title</div>
            <div class="card-subtitle1">Sub-Title</div>
          </div>
          <div id="page-cards-background" style="z-index: 1; height: 687px;">
            <div id="page-cards" style="z-index: 999;">
              <div class="card">
                xxx
                <br>xxx
                <br>xxx
                <br>xxx
                <br>xxx
                <br>xxx
                <br>xxx
                <br>
              </div>
              <div class="card">
                xxx
                <br>xxx
                <br>xxx
                <br>xxx
                <br>xxx
                <br>xxx
                <br>xxx
                <br> 888
                <br>xxx
                <br>xxx
                <br>xxx
                <br>xxx
                <br>xxx
                <br>xxx
                <br>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The overlap you've "fixed" was intentional. @tech2017

Answer (score 0):

OK...I solved the issue.

I was pretty sure I had gone down this route but apparently not.  I simply needed to add a position:absolute;  to the .background-card  css class.

I added some headers, text and a few bootstrap fields etc to prove it out a bit.

Here's a screenshot of the solution:

[image]

And heres the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class=" js flexbox canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Overlap</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
body {
  background-color: #81DFE8;
}

.background-card {
  background: #EFEFEF;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6));
  margin-top: 60px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #404040;
  z-index:-1;  
  position:absolute;      
}
.card {
  background: #EFEFEF;
  margin: 15px 30px;
  padding: 30px 75px 45px 50px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #404040;
}

#card-entity-header {
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.card-title {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.card-subtitle1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}
.card-subtitle1 small {
  font-size: 80%;
  font-style: italic;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>


</head>
<body>


<div>
    <div class="container"> 

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="col-sm-7 background-card">
                    <div id="card-entity-header" "="">
                        <div class="card-title">Title</div>
                        <div class="card-subtitle1">Sub-Title</div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="page-cards-background">
                        <div>&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <br><br>
                <div id="page-cards">
                    <div class="card row">
                            <h3>Card Title</h3>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut semper ullamcorper hendrerit. Cras ut ligula eu lorem finibus porta. Nunc lacinia, ex eu varius condimentum, ipsum enim aliquam magna, quis fringilla quam nunc nec erat.</p>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-12">Label</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lbl1">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-12 required">Label </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lbl2">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="card row">                              
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-12">Label</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lbl1">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-12 required">Label </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lbl2">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>


<script>

$("#page-cards").css("padding-top", 60 + parseInt($("#card-entity-header").height()));
$("#page-cards-background").height( parseInt($("#page-cards").height()) + 45);

</script>


</body></html>
```